# What might be some possible reason for the exception : 'Cannot find KieModule'?

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

I have four rule files and two of them are problematic. When I remove those two, drools runs fine. But with those two rule files, I am always getting the above mentioned exception.

I have kept one of those problematic files in this location : http://www.mediafire.com/file/6xsm8ilxysmyq3i/rulefile.drl. It is auto generated, and I am pretty sure it is an instant turn-off. It is difficult to check each and every line, so I was asking for suggestion what should I check to get a hint about the KieModule exception.

The other two files, with which all runs smooth, are of same structure, except probably they are smaller. So I am almost out of clue.

Any help is appreciated.

- no errors are shown in eclipse editor.

Can a syntactically correct rule throw 'Cannot find KieModule' exception upon firing ? In my case, as per the editor, the rule does not have syntactical error.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when drools compiler cannot able to find the kieModule in the rule engine. Check if there is a file as **src\main\resources\META-INF\kmodule.xml**  in your project file directory. If it is not there then create it. For more details read [this](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR3/drools-docs/html/KIEChapter.html).

Comment: Thanks for responding. Because my rule files is auto generated, I missed a simple restriction. I had same query name in two rule files, so the build was failing! Changing the query name solved my problem in this case.